# JavaScript not loading on Blazor Desktop Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, blazor

**Blazor Desktop Hybrid app in Winforms Javascript loading Errors**

I've been trying to find a fix to this for quite a while with no help from other stack overflow posts.

I am making a Blazor Desktop Hybrid app in Winforms and Im having a problem getting the javascript to load on the pages.

In my index.html file, the file that is run through the blazor webview, I've linked my javascript to it though it doesn't actually load on any of the pages.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js"></script>

<title>Title</title>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider-radio.js"></script>
<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plyr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/notify.js"></script>
```

I've seen elsewhere on stackoverflow that including `<script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js"></script>` before your other scripts should fix the problem because blazor hasnt loaded by the time it loads my scripts. However this didnt fix anything.

I have also tried to do load the scripts when the page loads by doing something like this.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime 

@code
{
    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/owl.carousel.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/select2.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/slider-radio.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/plyr.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "/js/main.js");
    }
}
```

suprisingly this did work, though it only works for the one page I executed this code on and I cant use this code on other pages as it seems to only work for one page at a time. Even after this fix, if I reload the page, all my javascripot content will disappear.

Hopefully you guys have an idea on what to do here since this is quite frustating.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: can you do one thing, once your js components disappear kindy hit `ctrl+f5` and see if they are back again or back for a split second. If thats the case it means problem is related to caching.

Comment: it happened to me as well, I removed all the js files i was injecting and started with one at a time and keep increasing the js file scripts untill it stopped working again. then i optimized that script or removed some of it which was not necessary it seemed to solved the issue for me. but i still dont know whats the underlying problem here